# How can I add an error if the input doesn't match with it's variable

Tags: java

I just got into java programming today and I made a calculator that I'm so proud of as a first project even though I took many parts of it from the internet like the Scanner code and how to allow input for the user, but I don't know how to print out an error if the input doesn't match the variable assigned to, ex: user inputs a string instead of an integer,

Comment: You need to add your code to the question, there by someone could provide you suggestions. An open ended question is likely to attract negative votes as you may have already observed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a try and catch statement to determine if the input you need is of the type that you want.

```
try {
  //  Block of code to try
}
catch(Exception e) {
  // error if it's not the type you are looking for
}
```

Comment: Do put this as an accepted answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

As the answer above states you can use try and and catch and also create a custom exception but that won't really help you because just copying it won't make you understand it and there is a lot of concepts you should learn before you take a look at that.
If you want to learn how to code/learn java I can recommend you this video series by BroCode https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBIUbTddde4&list=PLZPZq0r_RZOMhCAyywfnYLlrjiVOkdAI1
It's really good for beginners and easy to follow along

Comment: I tend to stick to experimenting and learning without videos because I find many kinda confusing and not fun to follow but this playlist is actually gold, I appreciate getting me a good free course because I can't afford a paid one lol thanks a lot